# Change default background color for matplotlib plots

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I am using `ipython` with `matplotlib`. Is it possible to configure the default background color for `matplotlib` plots? The curent (white) colour must come from somewhere. Is it possible to override it to, lets say, `#CCCCCC`?

Note: By default, I don't mean default for a given ipython notebook. I mean default for my `matplotlib` installation.

The solution suggested by @Ffisegydd works. however, after setting `axes.facecolor : F4EAEA`, I still get white edges around the plot:

[image]

How can I get rid of those?

## UPDATE:

now I have following set in my `/etc/matplotlibrc` and I have restarted ipython notebook after each change;

```
axes.facecolor      : F4EAEA   
figure.facecolor : F4EAEA  
figure.edgecolor : F4EAEA   
savefig.facecolor : F4EAEA    
savefig.edgecolor : F4EAEA
```

The plot looks the same as on the original screenshot. i.e. there is the white stripe around the plot.

## UPDATE2:

I am using ipython, and I have following custom css in my `~/.config/ipython/profile_nbserver/static/custom/custom.css`

```
div.output_area {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #F4EAEA !important;
  border: thin solid #4a4a4a;
}
```

Comment: Can you say how you're plotting? That looks like IPython, but it doesn't look like either the usual notebook interface or the qtconsole.

Comment: Your issue is probably with your custom css then, not matplotlib.

Comment: @mwaskom - the white edges around the plot are still part of the plot (i.e.: they come from matplotlib - notice the numbers on the axes). The `css` does not interfere in how images are rendered.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to set both the axes *and* figure background colors:

```
f = plt.figure(facecolor=".6")
ax = f.add_subplot(111, axisbg=".6")
ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2])
```

[image]

There is additionally a distinction between the facecolor for the interactive plot and what gets saved; you also have to pass `facecolor` to `f.savefig` if you want a uniform background on the resulting file.

You can change the defaults with the following fields in the `rcParams` dictionary:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams["figure.facecolor"]
mpl.rcParams["axes.facecolor"]
mpl.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"]
```

Note that this works a little unexpectedly in the IPython notebook with an inline backend, where the "saved" version of the figure you see below the cell is not controlled by the `figure` parameter, but by the `savefig` paramter.

Comment: thanks. I have now set all 3 (`axes.facecolor`, `figure.facecolor`, `savefig.facecolor`) to `F4EAEA` in `/etc/matplotlibrc`. But I still see the white edge (as shown on the original screenshot).

Comment: Ah, there is also an `edgecolor` parameter you will probably want to set.

Comment: the `axes.edgecolor` parameter seems to affect the black frame (line) around the plot. I want to keep that black. This is the same black line that you have on your screenshot as well.

Comment: Sorry, `figure.edgecolor` (and `savefig.edgecolor`) are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I have all the following set to `F4EAEA` and it still shows the white edge: `axes.facecolor`, `figure.facecolor`, `figure.edgecolor`, `savefig.facecolor`, `savefig.edgecolor`

Comment: Perhaps you'll need to update the question with what you are seeing, because I'm not clear what the problem is.

Comment: If you're changing the values in the `.matplotlibrc` file you'll need to restart your Python session before they take effect.

Comment: I have udated my question with the current status

Answer (score 13):

You can [customise matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) in a variety of ways.

If you're looking to customise across your entire computer then matplotlib uses the "matplotlibrc" configuration file as a default.

If you wish to edit this to change the default axes facecolor (the technical term for the background) then you'll need to uncomment and adjust this line:

`#axes.facecolor      : white   # axes background color`

If you wish to set your background colour to `#CCCCCC` then you should change the line to:

`axes.facecolor      : CCCCCC   # axes background color`

**N.B.** if you re-install matplotlib this *will be overwritten*. To prevent this you can save it in "HOME/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc" as the example comments state.

Should you wish to change it to a different colour temporarily then simply add the following at the top of your script:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = '111111' # Or any suitable colour...
```

If you should wish to modify an individual `matplotlib.axes` object then just use `ax.set_axis_bgcolor('...')`.

Comment: thanks. I have found `/etc/matplotlibrc` on my system. However, neither `axes.facecolor : #cccccc` nor `axes.facecolor : '#cccccc'` works.

Comment: @MartinVegter this works for me `axes.facecolor: eeddcc`

Comment: I've just tested it and I find the same as Diziet. If you uncomment the line and don't use the # symbol it works (testing on OS X Mavericks placing the file at ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc)

Comment: @Ffisegydd  - thanks, it works now. But there are still white edges around (I have added a screenshot to my original question)

Comment: @MartinVegter unfortunately I'm not able to replicate it. I have a white background as standard on my IPython notebook so it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/hHOdx14.png) with simply a grey axes face and white all around.

Comment: If you are using a Python virtual environment, like I am, you should find `matplotlibrc` in the Python virtual env directory.  For example: `./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`