# How to change matplotlib default settings to include white background on plots in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a dark theme on Jupyter Notebook and I find that when I make a plot using matplotlib, the plot looks like this:

[image]

So it is very hard to read the tick labels, as it seems that although the plot background is white, the background in this part is transparent.

I'm aware that this can be fixed on a plot by plot basis by using the following lines of code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
sns.scatterplot(train.X, train.y)
```

But is there a way to set a global property of matplotlib so that I don't need to do this each time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default background color for matplotlib plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246602/change-default-background-color-for-matplotlib-plots)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest I can think of:

```
sns.set()
sns.scatterplot(df.x,df.y)
```

Output:

[image]